# Spring Boot JAR doesn't contain classes in src folder

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I was upgrading the Spring version of our project and I noticed that the src/ folder doesn't appear as classes when I open the file as an Archive. Instead all I found was an /org folder where I found Spring.

It actually looked like this,
[image]

The strange thing was that we got the classes nicely before (as you would expect in JARs) in Spring 1.3.x.RELEASE

My pom.xml looks like this,

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
<groupId>spring.mvn</groupId>
<artifactId>dummySpringMvn</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>

    <mvn.compiler.version>3.3</mvn.compiler.version>

    <spring.framework.version>4.3.8.RELEASE</spring.framework.version>
    <start-class>dummySpringMvn.main.Main</start-class>

</properties>

<packaging>jar</packaging>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>${start-class}</mainClass>
                <layout>ZIP</layout>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found my classes in BOOT-INF folder!

[image]

This I found thanks for the article https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/executable-jar.html.

Furthermore, the project I upgraded was a library to another project. I was able to keep the folder of JARs as conventional creating the JAR without invoking `spring-boot-maven-plugin`

Comment: I am having the same problem but I have my start-class and main-class configured.
I have a property <start-class>com.example.myartifact.Main</start-class> and my spring-boot-maven-plugin configured with <mainClass>${start-class}</mainClass>